# Type return value when recursively re-mapping keys in object

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a mapper which takes in any object, and if there is a key named 'fields' in it, it's replaced by its contents. So for example,

```
const obj = { x: 'hey', fields: { y: 'you' } }
const mapped = contentfulMapper(obj);

// mapped = { x: 'hey', y: 'you' }
```

Or

```
const givenObj = {
  a: "sdf",
  w: { 
    a2: 343,
    a3: true,
    fields: {
      a4: "ll",
      q: {
        fields: {
          a5: [2, 4, "lk"]
        }, 
      },
    },
  }, 
};
const mapped = contentfulMapper(givenObj);

/* mapped = {
  a: "sdf",
  w: { 
    a2: 343,
    a3: true,
    a4: "ll",
    q: {
      a5: [2, 4, "lk"]
    }, 
  }, 
}; */
```

Returning a `Record<string, unknown>` isn't great though, so my question is how can I type this correctly?

```
type TContentfulModel = {
  fields?: undefined | Record<string, TContentfulModel>;
};


const contentfulMapper = (
  obj: Record<string, TContentfulModel | unknown>
) => {
  let out: Record<string, unknown> = {};

  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const field = obj[key] as TContentfulModel;
    if (key === 'fields') {
      const mappedField = contentfulMapper(field);
      out = { ...out, ...mappedField };
      
    } else {
      out[key] =
        typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key])
          ? contentfulMapper(field)
          : obj[key];
    }
  });

  return out;
};
```

Comment: Is the idea here that it will traverse the object's properties recursively in search of `fields` at any depth and under any property, and bring that to the top, spreading it?

Comment: Yes almost - but not to the top, just one level up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. Please go through it, let me know if don't get anything. I will add any needed explanation, then.

```
type TContentfulModelExtended = {
  fields: TContentfulModelExtended | TContentfulModel
  [key: string]: any
}

type TContentfulModel = {
  [key: string]: any
}

// if `T` has `fields`, we omit that key, keep rest,
// and take it's intersection with the flatten nested fields
type Flat<T extends TContentfulModelExtended | TContentfulModel> = T extends TContentfulModelExtended
  ? Omit<T, 'fields'> & Flat<T['fields']>
  : T

type MyObjType = {
  a: string
  fields: {
    b: number
    c: boolean
    fields: {
      d: number[],
      fields: {
        e: Promise<number>
      }
    }
  }
}

type Flattened = Flat<MyObjType>

const obj: Flattened = {
  a: 'abc',
  b: 3,
  c: false,
  d: [3],
  e: Promise.resolve(3)
}


const contentfulMapper = <O extends TContentfulModelExtended | TContentfulModel>(obj: O) => {
  let out: Flat<O> = {} as any;

  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const field = obj[key];
    if (key === 'fields') {
    // @ts-ignore
      const mappedField = contentfulMapper(field);
      out = { ...out, ...mappedField };
      
    } else {
      out[key] =
        typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key])
          ? contentfulMapper(field)
          : obj[key];
    }
  });

  // @ts-ignore
  return out;
};

const givenObj = {
  a: 'sdf',
  fields: {
    a2: 343,
    a3: true,
    fields: {
      a4: 'll',
      fields: {
        a5: [2, 4, 'lk']
      }
    }
  }
}

const objSpreaded = contentfulMapper(givenObj)
objSpreaded.a // all props from `a` to `e` works properly
objSpreaded.a2
objSpreaded.a3
objSpreaded.a4
objSpreaded.a5
objSpreaded.f // expected error
```

[[Playground]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgwgewHbAigZgVwDYFkEAmE2AogB6pJEFQC8UA3gFBRToCWxBAzgFyyIUaYFjyFi5StSgAfAckoic+IthZQA2gGsIIft2AAndkgDmAXX4BDJCCYBfJk1CR5QjMvHY6jddt36RiYW1rYOTgD0EVDs6FAABjDxUAAWVtwJHFzc8QA0UADu0AgAtuzAUMBpFTog+ToQYFCGEAa5TFFQNjTAVjoxwADkGSaohtwQAMbA7MiF5SmVKdDo2FbAlFBIrag0Wdg8zuDQAGJrwAA8MFAQFGg8boqiKhJ3VBA0cvAKws9eAHw+a63KQZb7uJRiVSSe4fdQAfigAHkypcYPlBvseINAQAyKBndZXDSYzgHbiDcz-dT8GBOFzQXAgJEAIwAVjBjj5mKwrIFjGZ1Fi+L5WKwWfwkJgSiyIIZ1KxJvwWQgENgIDYFWwyTx+DyxawCJLpbLDBpzO0DaxhXqtQaIPwAAqGUrsCYXKUyuXUq1QRwG-1+8JHVyEjZoD4+MMXJmsjnHalMSbIAxQBDs-hhyiR+j6vlQQZWFmTQaWqASqAAZjLSrYVmwEzLRs0lYt6gdUGdromADoWtw1QA3CAACkrAEpg0mUxVkxDnlYwJBDD4Lkibm8HuCnp5oZvI19BDuocR-iP02z+Ejx3RAfr1RUEJhgJnzmvAbn7F0MjYQABuJxWDjKZgB7WpuHPdlxx7dAEEMEgrEmFIRxHWob1oO8tTnVMsR8C9-BAcwAINWIoFQ3Q6FoehSWyQYb31VhOgAAWAbgAFp2FMJA4IgO0oGwioSkXSACBOHUfDnY9cGEuURyxcdiKtJ8KlzKAe3U5T8nUnshKXD4xK4P1FINLUv2ICZRSU58CPMOg+NYBkEDifDalsqjqIvEDBigXF8QAQgAQUMQwrBAHs3SCkKQEgtkbMnX0DURSTfmUGTDDknV4oS1h+Bc3QiNM9R7AUwCoGY1iOK4nj1BaYBMEMJA02fAD7AA6ckFTUx2GHJA425dR82GAh0FLIUdRFBiugAJn4SsABZqy1KxK34IxMAgMtrXG21fSsOb+EGbBsFG30bUs3aAFZ+A0Kb8jmjFsC0Sk+MDVhA0cRx2tTC8AGUwBaKxpHoZKPDwNKRy6nq40nX7-o1ageysMronrbx-oQMAMnQF0SgSKxkmABAEggZICjgrQMnR5dsDsWGAYRqwpqYOn4Y+RHK2Z9k-vptm9s5tludZghEYu-nBcBtm4k6W5IGmSM5RdQwgA)

Please note, I have added compiler directive comments `// @ts-ignore` to get rid of infinite depth error.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's not quite what I was looking for, I think. If I understand then it flattens completely, whereas my map replaces any 'fields' key by its value, at any depth. So for example `const givenObj = {
  a: "sdf", w: { a2: 343, a3: true, fields: { a4: "ll", fields: { a5: [2, 4, "lk"], }, }, }, };` should turn into `const mappedObj = { a: "sdf", w: { a2: 343, a3: true,  a4: "ll", a5: [2, 4, "lk"], }, },};`

Comment: Could you please add that example in proper format in the question?

Comment: Yes - I have added it now.